# r bind all dataframes with names matching string

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

I have hundreds of dataframes whose names end either with "_flow" or "_rain", and I would like to rbind them all into two dataframes – one for flow data and one for rain data.

I guess the equivalent of this in Linux would be:

```
cat *_flow.csv >> flow.csv
cat *_rain.csv >> rain.csv
```

How do I do this in R?

Comment: Something like `all_flow <- do.call("rbind", mget(ls(pattern="flow")))` should work

Comment: Lots of ways to do this, but if you had imported all your flow dataframes into a list, you could combine them all row-wise with Reduce(flowList, rbind)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to find the files and rbind them:

```r
files <- grep("_flow|_rain", dir(), value = TRUE)
  
library(vroom)

data <- vroom(files)
```